# Random folder name precedes Terminal prompt

Tags: linux, macos, unix, terminal

When I open new terminals, a random folder name ("screensaver") precedes my current working directory:

```
Last login: Sat Nov 16 18:35:56 on ttys002
screensaver:untitled folder userName$
```

I just worked on a project relating to a screensaver, so I'm not surprised by the actual word there. But I have no idea why it precedes all of my terminal prompts now.

Anyone know what this is and how to remove?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `bash` prompt was inadvertently changed.  Don’t panic! It can be fixed.

Look in your `.profile`, `.bash_profile` or `.bashrc` and see if a line that reads `screensaver` with possibly more text exists. If you can please post to the question for more specific help on removing.

More details on customizing your `bash` prompt can be found on [this site](http://beckism.com/2009/02/better_bash_prompt/). Should give you insight on how `bash` prompts work, how you can customize and—in this case—clean it up.

**EDIT:** Also, it might be worth it to check the system `bash`/`profile` defaults in one—or both—of these two files:

```
/etc/profile
```

Or this:

```
/etc/bashrc
```

Comment: I've opened and looked for `screensaver` in `.profile`, `.bash_profile` or `.bashrc` but it does not appear in any of them.

Comment: Thanks, that link you provided really helped. I did an `echo PS1` and saw that my host name was somehow changed to `screensaver`. I ran `sudo scutil --set HostName mynew.hostname` and was able to change it. Thanks!